# Javascript : calling method to fill innerHTML not working, the method is kind of "stringyfied" instead of being interpreted

Tags: javascript

When i try to fill some innerHTML with a method of an object I got an issue. Strangely, reffering to a function works. But this second way isnt convenient for what I would like to do, that is why I ask for help.
Is there a way to make this work ?

There is some code to explain my problem :

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id = "content1"></div>
    <div id = "content2"></div>
    <script>
        var object1 = { 'render' : () => { return 'a'; } }
        var object2 = { 'render' : setContent() }
        function setContent() { return 'b'; }

        document.querySelector('#content1').innerHTML = object1.render; // Not working
        document.querySelector('#content2').innerHTML = object2.render; // Working
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And that is the render :

```
() => { return 'a'; }
b
```

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: You should call the method, not just refer to it. The latter "works", because the value of `object2.render` is the value returned from `setContent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Crystal clear !

Answer (score 3):

`object1`'s `render` is the function signature, not the value returned from the function, which is why it looks "stringyfied"
`object2`'s `render` is the returned value from `setContent()`

If you want that anonymous function in there you can do it like so,

```
var object1 = { 'render' : (() => { return 'a'; })(); }
```